# Downloading and Installing Android SDK for Eclipse Mars

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

Can anyone here please provide me with the proper link for Android SDK and Installation of SDK for Eclipse Mars, I have searched a lot, but I didn't find anything other than Android Studio,

I am using eclipse because android studio is not working on my laptop, its very heavy and my laptop takes more time to open and run the program,

so If any one has the better knowledge for downloading and installation, then please provide me here..

and What I am trying to looking at Android developer website, they changed it for only Android Studio. Whenever I open any old link, it is redirecting me to Android Studio, is It true?? Please provide me with some more detail about it.

Thank  you

Comment: Eclipse is not supported anymore. You cannot use higher level build tools with eclipse. In short, do not use eclipse for developing Android apps. CurrentlyThere is no alternative to Android Studio.

Comment: You should use Android Studio. Try running Android Studio in Power Save Mode (File->Power Save Mode) it will disable background processes, and might run smoother on your laptop.

Comment: Does emulator will response properly in power saver mode???

Comment: I'm not sure... just try it.

Comment: @RaviShankarLadhar If you need a smoother emulator, then try Genymotion

Answer (score 0):

You can download eclipse [ADT plugin](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) from here (note that it is not the latest).

Also, there is one more [helpful link](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) for getting latest available releases for eclipse (ADT 23.0.7 since August 2015).

By the way, at least for me is very confusing that Android Studio working worse than eclipse. I found that Android Studio is far better than eclipse (but that is only my personal opinion).

**Anyway, that is more important: Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android and migration to it is recommended. Eclipse is not supported anymore.**

Answer (score 0):

How about you download [Eclipse Neon](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers-includes-incubating-components/neon1) with the [Andmore project](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore)?

While Eclipse is not officially supported by Google, this project has forked the Android ADT plugin and is being maintained on the side.